# TypeScript build using common unable to find require

Tags: angular, systemjs

I have been developing an angular 2 application which i downloaded from angular2 quickstart application. When I run and build the application it shows require is not defined.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

Below is the code how i am including system.js

```
//index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <title>Angular QuickStart</title>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/styles/main.css">

   <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
   <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
   <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
   <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
   <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

   <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
   <script>
     System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
   </script>
```

Comment: are you trying to build with commonjs and try to importit

Comment: yes, commin js is used while building

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when you try to build with commonjs and try to load with systemjs loader. In you tsconfig.json change the module to system.

my tsconfig.json below.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true

  }
}
```